# Pinch to Zoom for an ImageView inside ViewPager ? onTouch Event not working?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I went through numerous posts in stack overflow but could not get the possible solution for this.

```
package com.sourcebits.gallerygestures;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.FloatMath;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    /**
     * 
     * @author Rajeev N B
     * 
     */

    public class GalleryActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

        /**
         * Activity Context
         */
        private GalleryActivity context;

        /**
         * List of drawables
         */
        private int[] mImages = new int[6];

        /**
         * ViewPager for displaying images
         */
        private ViewPager viewPager;

        /**
         * Matrices used for Pinch and Zoom
         */
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

        // We can be in one of these 3 states
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // Remember some things for zooming
        PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
            context = GalleryActivity.this;
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @author Rajeev N B Adapter for displaying the images
         * 
         */
        private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            private int[] mImages = { R.drawable.background, R.drawable.koskula,
                    R.drawable.wallpaper, R.drawable.wallpap, R.drawable.gr,
                    R.drawable.balck };
            private int pos;
            private ImageView imageView;

            /**
             * Default Constructor
             */
            public ImagePagerAdapter() {

            }

            /**
             * Get the Count of the Pages for the View Pager
             */
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mImages.length;
            }

            /**
             * Get the View from the Object
             */
            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }

            /**
             * Create a new Item in the viewPager
             */
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (pos < mImages.length)
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos + 1);
                        Log.v("Next", "" + pos);
                    }
                });

                prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (pos > 0)
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos - 1);
                        Log.v("Next", "" + pos);
                    }
                });

                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.dimen.padding_medium);
                imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
                ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
                imageView.setOnTouchListener(context);
                return imageView;
            }

            /**
             * Destroy the Items
             */
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Pinch to zoom Functionality
         */
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            // Handle touch events here...
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

        /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

        /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }
    }
```

Basically an Image `GalleryView` implemented using `ViewPager`.
I am inflating the image views based on the position from the drawable array.
Now I want to implement Pinch to Zoom functionality for my application. But I am not able to get the Touch event on the `ImageView` inside my `ViewPager`. I tested my `onTouchEvent` pinch to zoom without the `ViewPager`, It works fine. It does not work with View Pager. I guess the `ViewPager` is not taking touch events for the child views.
I need to have pinch to zoom to the `ImageView` inside `ViewPager` ?

Answer (score 0):

if your viewpager is using an imageView then you can use touchImageView. By following below link you can the source code just use that and you can able to fix your issue.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java

finally, just replace your current imageview with this custom view. If any problems while implementing let me know i will try to clarify on this.